# How to get virtuemart store default currency details in components?

Tags: joomla, components, virtuemart

I want to show currency symbol and currency code in my component, but don't know how to do it
try id

```
if (!class_exists( 'currencydisplay' ))
    require(JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR .'/components/com_virtuemart/helpers/currencydisplay.php');
    $currency = CurrencyDisplay::getInstance();

echo '<pre>';
print_r($currency);
exit;
```

but it is throughing an error like ..

```
Class 'VmModel' not found in /administrator/components/com_virtuemart/helpers/currencydisplay.php on line 46
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Instead of loading currency mode try to load VM config class then you will get access to all VM models like below.

```
if (!class_exists( 'VmConfig' )) require(JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR.DS.'components'.DS.'com_virtuemart'.DS.'helpers'.DS.'config.php');
        $config = VmConfig::loadConfig();


    $currency_model = VmModel::getModel('currency');
    $displayCurrency = $currency_model->getCurrency( $this->product->product_currency );

    echo $displayCurrency->currency_name;
    echo $displayCurrency->currency_code_3;
    echo $displayCurrency->currency_symbol;
```

Hope this helps you.